# Closing as a duplicate based on answer content

Tags: discussion, specific-question

When a question is put on hold or closed as a duplicate, the text

> **This question already has an answer here:**

Appears on the question body.

Furthermore, on https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates, it is outlined that main reason we close questions as duplicates is to keep answers in one place.

For the [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330283/structs-with-same-name-and-same-meber-types-but-different-member-names) that I am unsure about, there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485168/is-struct-packing-deterministic) that has an accepted answer that includes the information that the OP was looking for, but the question itself was not exactly the same.  In this case, should we still close as a duplicate for the goal of keeping answers in one place?

Comment: Somehow I think that it may be duplicate if the duplicate answer contains the information for the question, but on the otherside then we could mark all question as duplicate to an answer which links to the C standard ...

Comment: Ironically it seems my own question here is a duplicate under my own definition, which is fine by me :)

Comment: But for me it remains a mystery if the questions you linked are duplicate or not, because this duplicate referes different questions.

Comment: I actually find it quite funny that this question, which asks if two questions are duplicate, is marked as duplicate to a question which asks if two completly different questions are duplicate.

Comment: A question is only a duplicate if all possible answers to the question are also possible answers to the target question and vice versa.